# Identification of task bar (or desktop) icons in screencasts?

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

Is there a best practice for figuring out what certain task bar icons represent, such as when you see them in a video instructor's screencast and you're curious if it's an app you should add to your stack?

I tried taking a screenshot of the screenscasted icon and putting it into a Google image search, but this didn't work.

Comment: I find that google image search matches entire images against entire images. Try trimming your image to just the icon and doing the image search on that.

Comment: You may have better luck asking the instructor or asking on a computing forum and providing your screenshot. (This isn't a forum.)

Comment: @Ouroborus I know this isn't a forum (I'm a heavy user of StackOverflow and SE, about 6,000 rep overall - so a bit more experienced), but I think it's an on-topic question. I can't ask an instructor in a MOOC and I think it would be a highly useful skill to have as a user. I'm fairly sure there are web services out there related to this. I appreciate the suggestion, but that is how I originally searched using Google Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crowd sourcing. Provide your screenshot and question asking what software the icon is for in a forum focused on computer software. Were it me, I'd try [the forums over at Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/).